# What to do when spy++ doesnt give any details to extract from software?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have some software that needs some info mining like getting text from controls/listiews etc.. The thing is that spy++ cant detect any controls, much less the text from them.

I figure the software is made in something unknown to c++/mfc/winapi

So what are my choices here, what can i do?

It seems winapi wont work here at all?

Comment: Windowless controls were popular in the early ActiveX days.  They are back, WPF apps are windowless too for example.  Yes, the accessibility interfaces that screen readers use for visually impaired users is your only hope.  Try one.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a window less UI toolkit called DirectUI, other applications might use similar controls. HWND based tools are not going to help you there, your best option is probably to try the [accessibility api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317990%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Spy++ works directly with the child window controls and menu's that are not used so much anymore.

As such, the most reliable way to extract information nowdays from Windows is to use the [UI Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486375%28VS.85%29.aspx) APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The text might be custom-rendered by the app. Try Anders' suggestion of the accessibility API first but, if that fails, you're into OCR territory.